# Can't seem to resolve KeyedByTypeCollection?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012, portable-class-library

I'm playing around with .NET portable to create a library and have been encountering some issues when trying to create instances of KeyedByTypeCollection.

I've checked my references (.NET Portable Subset) and System.Collections.Generic seems to be showing the KeyedByTypeCollection.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404549.aspx - MSDN seems to indicate that it should be supported as well.

Despite that, Visual Studio & the compiler still seem unable to resolve the type.

Any idea what I might be missing here?  Thanks!

Comment: Do you have  a reference to System.ServiceModel.dll?

Comment: Whenever I try to add it, the dialogue disappears and it isn't added to my references.  But when I look at .NET portable subset in the explorer, it shows up in that listing there...

Comment: What combination of platforms are you targeting in your portable library?  (As far as adding the reference goes, the portable class library project should now automatically reference all framework assemblies that are available.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation is wrong. KeyedByTypeCollection is not supported in portable library. What's your usage?