# Protobuf-net KeyedCollection serialization

Tags: c#, list, serialization, protobuf-net, keyedcollection

I need to serialize/deserialize a KeyedCollection with protobuf-net, can I just serialize a list?

If so, what is the most efficient way to convert-back the List to the KeyedCollection?

Here follows a sample code that shows the case:

```
public class FamilySurrogate
{
    public List<Person> PersonList { get; set; }

    public FamilySurrogate(List<Person> personList)
    {
        PersonList = personList;
    }


    public static implicit operator Family(FamilySurrogate surrogate)
    {
        if (surrogate == null) return null;

        var people = new PersonKeyedCollection();
        foreach (var person in surrogate.PersonList)  // Is there a most efficient way?
            people.Add(person);

        return new Family(people);

    }

    public static implicit operator FamilySurrogate(Family source)
    {
        return source == null ? null : new FamilySurrogate(source.People.ToList());
    }

}

public class Person
{
    public Person(string name, string surname)
    {
        Name = name;
        Surname = surname;
    }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string Fullname { get { return $"{Name} {Surname}"; } }
}

public class PersonKeyedCollection : System.Collections.ObjectModel.KeyedCollection<string, Person>
{        
    protected override string GetKeyForItem(Person item) { return item.Fullname; }
}

public class Family
{
    public Family(PersonKeyedCollection people)
    {
        People = people;
    }

    public PersonKeyedCollection People { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I have never explicitly considered `KeyedCollection<...>`. I suspect `Dictionary<...>` will work just fine, though. There is not currently any support for this scenario.

Comment: Hi @MarcGravell, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7566657/dictionary-or-keyedcollection) it would be enough to serialize the list, anyway let me know if you add the support for this in future, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

## Solution?

**.NET Platform Extensions 6** has an implementation of the KeyedCollection, [KeyedByTypeCollection Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.keyedbytypecollection-1?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0). This has [a constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.keyedbytypecollection-1.-ctor?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0#system-collections-generic-keyedbytypecollection-1-ctor(system-collections-generic-ienumerable((-0)))) which accepts an IEnumerable. The downside to this implementation is that the keys *are the items*, and it doesn't appear to allow you to change that. If you're already inheriting KeyedCollection, you may as well follow the implementation [here](https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/blob/3676252f88951c754c8b124c5da3d108b88d4db1/src/dotnet-svcutil/lib/src/FrameworkFork/System.ServiceModel/System/ServiceModel/KeyedByTypeCollection.cs#L17) and go by Microsoft's lead; they just iterate and call `Add()`.

### See also

- [Uses of KeyedByTypeCollection in .Net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/330387/uses-of-keyedbytypecollection-in-net)
- [Can't seem to resolve KeyedByTypeCollection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11183016/cant-seem-to-resolve-keyedbytypecollection)
- [What are .NET Platform Extensions on learn.microsoft.com?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53097067/what-are-net-platform-extensions-on-docs-microsoft-com)
- [Linq with custom base collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371174/linq-with-custom-base-collection)
- [Collection Initializers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers#collection-initializers)

## Previous thoughts

I'm also trying to tackle this issue from a Linq query perspective, possibly related posts:

- [Cannot implicitly convert type System.Collections.Generic.List back to Object after linq query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57188104/cannot-implicitly-convert-type-system-collections-generic-list-back-to-object-af)
- [dotnet/runtime: Why is KeyedCollection abstract?](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/22139)

The core issue seems to be that [KeyedCollectedion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.keyedcollection-2) does not contain a constructor that takes any form of ICollection to initialize its data with. The base class of KeyedCollection, [Collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.collection-1.-ctor), does however. The only option seems to be writing your own constructor for your KeyedCollection class that iterates over a collection and adds each element to the current instance.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

public class VariableList<T> : KeyedCollection<string, T>
{
    // KeyedCollection does not seem to support explicitly casting from an IEnumerable,
    // so we're creating a constructor who's sole purpose is to build a new KeyedCollection.
    public VariableList(IEnumerable<T> items)
    {
        foreach (T item in items)
            Add(item);
    }

    // insert other code here
}
```

*This seems really inefficient though, so I hope someone corrects me...*

Edit: John Franco wrote a [blogpost](http://buiba.blogspot.com/2009/06/so-i-get-onto-phone-for-my-first-job.html) wherein they hack together a solution for genericly casting a List with covariants (in 2009!) This doesn't look like a very good way to do things.

Looking at System.Linq.Enumerable's [implementation](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/5697c29004a34d80acdaf5742d7e699022c64ecd/System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs#L329) of ToList, Linq also iterates and Adds to the new collection.

Comment: Indeed that's what I have done after looking at how Linq works :)