# How do I know which Platform Extensions do I need for .NET Standard?

Tags: c#, .net, portability, .net-standard-2.0, dll-reference

I ran the [.NET Portability Analyzer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ConnieYau.NETPortabilityAnalyzer) against a class library that I want to use from my own .NET Standard class library. The class I want to use has a dependency on .NET framework. The compatibility results were 91% for .NET Standard and 100% for .NET Standard + Platform Extensions.

From what I've [read](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53097067/1057791) I understand that Platform Extensions means that there are some nuget packages that if I add to my project I'll get the 100% compatibility.

The question is how do I know what nuget packages should I install? All I could find was this [page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/index?view=dotnet-plat-ext-2.1) that just lists a bunch of namespaces - how to determine which of them do I need for my project?

[image: .NET Portability Analyzer Results]

Comment: It is in effect telling you that your app isn't portable and *might* be portable if you can find substitutes.  If you only plan to target the Windows platform, probably necessary, then just add a reference to the Windows Compatibility Pack: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Windows.Compatibility/2.1.1  Guessing a bit at the best version btw.

Comment: look under "Details" tab to see more.

Comment: @magicandre1981 Thank you, so I guess this is the answer.. I have to look in the details tab, then copy the type name and paste it into the Browse tab in the Manage Nuget Packages for solution and then I guess I'm covered.

Comment: I'm not sure it's that simple (I wish it was). I did exactly this and added [System.Drawing.Common](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Drawing.Common/). My assembly built for Net Standard, but can fail at runtime on Linux with a `PlatformNotSupportedException`.