# How do I write a ReadOnlySequence into a Stream?

Tags: c#, stream, azure-blob-storage

I get data from a `PipeReader` as a `ReadOnlySequence` which I need to write into a `Stream`, but I can't figure out how do to that? Here's my current code:

```
Stream blobStream = await blobClient.OpenWriteAsync(false); 

while(true)
{
    var readResult = await reader.ReadAsync();
    ReadOnlySequence<byte> buffer = readResult.Buffer;

    // here I want to write the buffer to the Stream - but how?
    // e.g. blobStream.WriteAsync(buffer) doesn't work as there is no matching method overload
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If it's writing from an Azure blob, you should use `DownloadToAsync(stream)`

```cs
public static async Task DownloadBlobToStreamAsync(
    BlobClient blobClient,
    string localFilePath)
{
    //This could be any Stream
    FileStream fileStream = File.OpenWrite(localFilePath);

    await blobClient.DownloadToAsync(fileStream);

    fileStream.Close();
}
```

To upload from a stream to blob storage use `UploadAsync(stream)`

```cs
public static async Task UploadFromStreamAsync(
    BlobContainerClient containerClient,
    string localFilePath)
{
    string fileName = Path.GetFileName(localFilePath);
    BlobClient blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient(fileName);

    //This could be any stream
    FileStream fileStream = File.OpenRead(localFilePath);
    await blobClient.UploadAsync(fileStream, true);
    fileStream.Close();
}
```

Comment: `using FileStream fileStream =...` and remove `fileStream.Close();`

Comment: The PipeReader stream I have is coming from the body of an HTTP request. I also want to use a PipeReader for performance reasons. So I need PipeReader to Azure blob.

Comment: @stefan.at.kotlin Just convert the PipeReader to a Stream using the AsStream() method.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.pipelines.pipereader.asstream?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0

Comment: @BronDavies Thanks, didn't see that yet. But I am wondering what the version "NET platform extensions 7" in the docs means? Is that method cross platform?

Comment: @stefan.at.kotlin It basically means there are extension methods available in a nuget package and not as a core framework method.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53097067/what-are-net-platform-extensions-on-docs-microsoft-com  It seems as though these are generally considered cross-platform compatible.