# Cannot implicitly convert type System.Collections.Generic.List back to Object after linq query

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, arraylist, collections

I have an Address class and a collection of Addresses called AddressCollection  “objAddresses”

```
namespace MemberModel
{
    [Serializable()]
    public class Address 
    {
        public int MemberID { get; set; }

        public string MemberStreet { get; set; }

        public string MemberCity { get; set; }

        public string MemberState { get; set; }

        public string MemberZipcode { get; set; }
    }
}

using System.Collections.Generic;
namespace MemberModel
{
    [System.Serializable()]
    public class AddressCollection : System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<Address>
    {
    }
}
```

I am using Linq to parse down this AddressCollection to get Addrsses with zipcodes that only contain 1173.

```
MemberModel.AddressCollection objAddresses = new MemberModel.AddressCollection ();
DataAccess dal = new Member.DataAccess();

objAddresses = dal.GetAllMemberAddresses();

var objSearch = from searchAddresses in objAddresses
    .WheresearchAddresses => searchAddresses.MemberZipcode.Contains("1173"))
    select searchAddresses;
```

This works I get 40 addresses out of 1000.

The problem is now I need to convert this objSearch back into the AddressCollection object objAddresses.  I get this error 
**Cannot implicitly convert type**

> Cannot implicitly convert type System.Collections.Generic.List to
>       MemberModel.AddressCollection

```
objAddresses = objSearch.ToList();
```

Comment: Generally if you have a collection and need to convert to another type, you can use a loop to add elements from the collection to a newly instantiated object of the type you want. Its hard to replicate what you have without more code though.

Comment: @David Bentley  i use this same code within vb.net and it works perfect.  But C# has a problem with this conversion.  I must be able to cast it or something without putting a loop on every one of these linq querys that would be so monotonous

Comment: You could just create a conversion method or extend what `AddressCollection` can do by following below. Its not much extra code. Olivier Jacot-Descombes answer is elegant but I will post my option for you also.

Comment: Your search code is not compiling. Yo are mixing LINQ query syntax with extension method syntax and there is a left brace missing. Also, I don't see the part where you are converting `objSearch` back into the `AddressCollection`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're declaring this:

```
MemberModel.AddressCollection objAddresses = new MemberModel.AddressCollection();
```

The declared type of `objAddresses` is `AddressCollection`. C# is statically typed. Once you have declared a variable with a given type, you cannot assign anything to it which is not of that type.

That's why you're getting an compile error here:

```
var objSearch = from searchAddresses in objAddresses
    .WheresearchAddresses => searchAddresses.MemberZipcode.Contains("1173"))
    select searchAddresses;

objAddresses = objSearch.ToList(); // compile error
```

`objSearch` is an `IEnumerable<Address>`.
Calling `.ToList()` gets you a `List<Address>`. You can't assign a `List<Address>` to a variable declared as type `AddressCollection`. You can only assign an `AddressCollection` or something that inherits from it to that variable.

You can do this:

```
objAddresses = new MemberModel.AddressCollection(objSearch.ToList());
```

Now you're creating a new instance of `AddressCollection` that contains all of the items in the `List`. Then you're assigning the an object of the correct type - `AddressCollection` -  to the variable.

---

As a side point, when you initially declare the variable you're assigning a new collection but you're never using it. You're just replacing it later with a new collection.

You could just eliminate this:

```
MemberModel.AddressCollection objAddresses = new MemberModel.AddressCollection ();
```

and declare the variable later where you assign it:

```
var objAddresses = new MemberModel.AddressCollection(objSearch.ToList());
```

---

And, finally, hungarian notation is dead. You don't need the `obj` prefix on variable names. People will look at it funny. You can just call the variable `addresses`.

Answer (score 0):

`Collection<T>` has a constructor accepting a `IList<T>`. Add a correpsponding constructor to the `AddressCollection` class and call the base constructor.

```
public class AddressCollection : System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<Address>
{
    public AddressCollection(IList<Address> addresses)
        : base(addresses)
    {
    }

    public AddressCollection()
    {
    }
}
```

Now you can convert arrays and lists with

```
objAddresses = new AddressCollection(objSearch.ToList());
```

See:

- [Collection<T> Constructors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.collection-1.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8)
- [Calling the base constructor in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12051/calling-the-base-constructor-in-c-sharp)

Comment: I don't find your code where you are converting a `System.Collections.Generic.List` to a `MemberModel.AddressCollection`. Please post the faulty code.

Answer (score 0):

Another simple way of doing it. I am also guessing the parameter is `IList`. If not try `System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<Address>` instead.

```
    public AddressCollection GetAddressList(IList<Address> addresses)
    {
        MemberModel.AddressCollection objAddresses = new MemberModel.AddressCollection();
        foreach (var item in addresses)
        {
            objAddresses.Add(item);
        }

        return objAddresses;
    }
```